# UIImagePickerController Shutter Detection

Tags: objective-c, events, uiimagepickercontroller

Is there a way to detect when the camera has finished taking a picture?

Currently I'm using the below method:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"END");
    _showAlert = NO;
    _alertIsShowing = NO;
    if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"], nil, nil, nil);
        _endAlerts = YES;
    }
    _imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    _saveBtn.hidden = NO;
}
```

That triggers after the user has clicked the "Use Photo" button. I want something that triggers as soon as the image is captured in the image picker view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the only way of doing this is to create my own overlay, which in and of itself is proving to be a pain the rear end.